# inflating an asset in a Runnable

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm running the following code vicariously in a Runnable.

```
LinearLayout assets = (LinearLayout)StaticRefernceToMyActivity.instance.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.assets, null);
```

I'm getting back

```
05-10 15:44:59.911: W/System.err(10163): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #110: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

** EDIT **

This code all works fine normally, but I've moved it all to the `doInBackground` of an `AsyncTask` and that's when I started getting weird issues like the one above.

Comment: android.R.* references the built-in resources, your_package.R obviously references your resources... What are trying to do?

Comment: I just revamped my question..

Comment: Do you have a file named "assets.xml" in your res/layout/ folder? If so please post that xml file and the full logcat trace so we can see what's happening.

Comment: I added an edit. Is that any help?

Comment: A little, you can only update the UI in onPostExecute() not doInBackground(). Is that your trouble?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the newer question:

-Do you have a custom view or fragment in that assets.xml file?  If so, it needs to have a parameterless constructor for the inflater to use.

-FYI, UI operations can result in a crash if performed outside the UI thread.  I'm not sure if just running an inflate qualifies, but if you get a CalledFromWrongThreadException, that's what's going on there.

Comment: I modded my question because this didn't end up being the problem. I gave you a +1 for the question you were answering though.

Comment: Thanks!  Attempting to answer the new question.  If I'm wrong, I'm also fresh out of guesses unless we can see the relevant code from assets.xml :)